# How do I sum up the value of a column where a given value exists in another column?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Each row in my sheet represents a transaction. One column (G) contains the client name and another column (H) contains the GP from the exchange.

I'm trying to make a report in another sheet that references these cells to get GP info for each of our clients.

The formula I'm trying to accomplish is this: **Sum up the GP (column H) from every row containing [ClientID] in `Column G`**

The `ClientID` is on Column G and `GP` is on Column H

I would like to make this process automated so that each time a transaction is entered, the Client GP sheet will be automatically updated.

Thanks.

Comment: =SUMIF(G:G,[ClientID],H:H). See [HERE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b)

Comment: [HERE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583?hl=en) is the documentation for Google sheets.

Comment: This is the right answer. Post it as an answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only so this can be closed out:

As per my comments use the SUMIF() function:

```
=SUMIF(G:G,[ClientID],H:H)
```

References: [GOOGLE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583?hl=en) and  [EXCEL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)